# Generate list of date/time objects matching required density and peak load

Tags: java, events, load-testing, scheduler

In order to test application with event load, I need a library, which would allow me to

- specify regular load, e.g N events/second, and duration (in seconds) of each load period
- specify peak load, e.g M events/second, and duration of peak load or number of events in peak load to generate
- specify number of peaks and it's position on test time interval (e.g, peaks on 1,5,7,10 seconds after test start)

Optionally it would be great to specify distinct event types, and configure system that regular load consists of 20% events of type A, 40% of type B and rest of type C, and for peak loads as well.

As a result, I want to get list of java.util.Date objects (ideally), or parseable date/time strings.

Is there something ready-to-use available, or this is subject for coding?